# mySQL database import data into structure

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a website that got hacked, and it messed up the whole website (deleted files and corrupted database). 
Now the current database which has updated records but it's missing the primary key columns on most of the tables. I need to import and overwrite the records of the current database into the old database.
So old database - STRUCTURE_db gets records overwritten from the current database - DATA_db.

How can I do it with phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Each table have one .frm file that have schema of table so that by using frm file you get schema of table in phpmy admin

Comment: I need to remove all data records from Structure_db and import all data from Data_db, using phpmyadmin

Comment: are you know about phpmyadmin ? import and export functionality

Comment: How can I import data only from another database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Got the First Step in phpMyAdmin, that is to create a duplicate database without data, structure only.
in phpMyAdmin, 
1-select the database to be copied, 
2-click on the Operations tab, 
3-under "Copy database to" field type the new Database name and 
4-Select "Structure only" option and 
5-Click GO.